# Reasons why Google Chrome is ignoring Cache-Control header

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, caching, browser

I have a specific asset on my server that responds requests with the following header:

```
cache-control:public,max-age=2592000,immutable
```

Sometimes the site might have to request the same file more than 10 times (The reason is not important). That's the reason why I configured this header.

Almost all mobile devices, desktop, and tables (along with the browsers) respect it, but some are not, they are just ignoring and requesting from the server again, E-V-E-R-Y single time. I'm using the BrowserStack to test, maybe the problem could be there, I'm not sure of anything now. Have you ever experienced such a thing? Is there a workaround, or something that I could do to debug it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`immutable` is an Extension Cache-Control directive and is not supported by all browsers.

According to [http://developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) :

> Extension Cache-Control directives are not part of the core HTTP caching standards document.

If you check [on the same page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#Browser_compatibility) you can see that Chrome does not support it.

You may be better off using a simpler directive, like:

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
```